# I wish to split the names of lists and allocate them in order R

Tags: r, string, list, names

I have a list of lists and for some of them the names are repetitive, even though the information in the lists themselves is not the same. Here is an example:

```
l.f[[" c225 && Gross Amount && Reporting Year of Account 2015 && 225 && Gross Amount && Reporting Year of Account 2016 && 225 && Gross Amount && Reporting Year of Account 2016 && 1"]]

l.f[[" c225 && Gross Amount && Reporting Year of Account 2015 && 225 && Gross Amount && Reporting Year of Account 2016 && 225 && Gross Amount && Reporting Year of Account 2016 && 2"]]

l.f[[" c225 && Gross Amount && Reporting Year of Account 2015 && 225 && Gross Amount && Reporting Year of Account 2016 && 225 && Gross Amount && Reporting Year of Account 2016 && 3"]]
```

The only thing that differentiates the names of these lists is the final digit in the name of each of them `(1,2,3)` in this case. What I wish to do is break down the names of these lists so that they're named like this:

```
l.f[[" c225 && Gross Amount && Reporting Year of Account 2015"]]

l.f[["225 && Gross Amount && Reporting Year of Account 2016"]]

l.f[["225 && Gross Amount && Reporting Year of Account 2016 1"]]
```

Is there any way to break it down like this in R?

Comment: Are _all_ the similar strings alike in the same way with just a differing digit at the end?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, the only thing that differentiates them is the digit at the end which can range from 1 to 7 depending on the list names

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to remove the characters after the `&&` and use `make.unique`

```
names(lst1) <- make.unique(sub("^([^&]+[&]+[^&]+[&]+[^&]+)\\s+.*", "\\1", names(lst1)))
```

#### data

```
names(lst1)
c(" c225 && Gross Amount && Reporting Year of Account 2015 && 225 && Gross Amount && Reporting Year of Account 2016 && 225 && Gross Amount && Reporting Year of Account 2016 && 1", 
 " c225 && Gross Amount && Reporting Year of Account 2015 && 225 && Gross Amount && Reporting Year of Account 2016 && 225 && Gross Amount && Reporting Year of Account 2016 && 2", 
 " c225 && Gross Amount && Reporting Year of Account 2015 && 225 && Gross Amount && Reporting Year of Account 2016 && 225 && Gross Amount && Reporting Year of Account 2016 && 3"
 )
```